# Url Mapping, Url redirection / rewriting

Tags: url, grails, redirect, url-rewriting, url-mapping

I want to redirect my '/' uri to a given controller's action. I used to do it via the following code in `UrlMappings.groovy`:

```
"/"(action: "highlights", controller: "project")
```

However, this does not rewrite the url in the browser. It redirects to the correct controller's action, but the browser's navigation Url is still at `myProject/`. I would like it to be updated to the "correct" uri so that reloads, etc. use the "correct" uri.

I tried:

```
"/"(uri: "/project/highlights")
```

but I get a status 404 response.

Any suggestions on how I should proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UrlMappings is only for how to map the url to your controller.action. It won't do any redirect. 
If you want to do url redirect, you probably need to setup a http server like apache in front of your application server or the easier way is to just setup a controller.action to do the redirect manually.

```
"/"(action: "redirect", controller: "project")
```

In the `project` controller, and `redirect` action, just redirect the user to your `highlights` action.

Comment: I did that, thanks. 

PS: if named "redirect", the controller's action overrides Grails' redirect() method

Answer (score 1):

Your application is deployed to `myProject/` context. Hence root (`"/"`) for your application is `myProject/`. What you want to do is to deploy your application to your server root context. You can do this by setting `grails.app.context = “/”` in your Config.groovy.